# DataGridView rows disappear with no apparent reason

Tags: c#, datagridview

I'm using a DataGridView to add, edit and view data. When the user presses a button I'd like to save all the edits he made. A decision is made at runtime based on a read-only cell value to determine whether it is necessary to add or edit the current record. So here's the code:

```
int bad = 0;
foreach ( DataGridViewRow row in grid.Rows ) {
    if ( IsValidRow( row ) ) {
        row.Cells[ "colStatus" ].Value = bmpTick;

        string id = ( string ) row.Cells[ "colID" ].Value;
        if ( id != null ) {
            customerManager.EditCustomer( new Guid( id ),
                newFirstName: ( string ) row.Cells[ "colFirstName" ].Value,
                newSecondName: ( string ) row.Cells[ "colSecondName" ].Value,
                newPhone: ( string ) row.Cells[ "colPhone" ].Value,
                newResidence: ( string ) row.Cells[ "colResidence" ].Value );
        }
        else {
            customerManager.AddCustomer(
                firstName: ( string ) row.Cells[ "colFirstName" ].Value,
                secondName: ( string ) row.Cells[ "colSecondName" ].Value,
                phone: ( string ) row.Cells[ "colPhone" ].Value,
                residence: ( string ) row.Cells[ "colResidence" ].Value );
        }
    }
    else bad += 1;
}
```

The problem is that after calling AddCustomer or EditCustomer all the rows but the first two disappear ( grid.Rows.Count becomes 2 ). The first row keeps its data while the second one has all of its cells empty. Here are AddCustomer and RemoveCustomer:

```
private List<Customer> _customers;

// ...

public void AddCustomer( 
    string firstName, 
    string secondName,
    string residence,
    string phone )
{
    Customer toAdd = new Customer( firstName, secondName, residence, phone );
    toAdd.CustomerEdited += this.CustomerEdited;

    _customers.Add( toAdd );
    _customers.Sort( );

    OnCustomerAdded( toAdd );
}

public void EditCustomer(
    Guid id,
    string newFirstName = "",
    string newSecondName = "",
    string newPhone = "",
    string newResidence = "" )
{

    Customer cus = _customers.Single( c => c.ID == id );

    if ( newFirstName != string.Empty ) cus.FirstName = newFirstName;
    if ( newSecondName != string.Empty ) cus.SecondName = newSecondName;
    if ( newPhone != string.Empty ) cus.Phone = newPhone;
    if ( newResidence != string.Empty ) cus.Residence = newResidence;
}
```

And this is Customer's constructor:

```
public Customer( 
    string firstName,
    string secondName,
    string residence,
    string phone )
{
    this._firstName = firstName;
    this._secondName = secondName;
    this._residence = residence;
    this._phone = phone;

    this.ID = Guid.NewGuid( );
}
```

As you can see I never edit the values retrieved from the cells so I really can't understand why the table gets destroyed.

**EDIT:**
I've followed the advice given by DavidHall in its comment (setting the DataSource property of the DataGridView to point at Customer). The code is very similar to the code I posted above; iterate over customerBindingSource.List and determine the correct method to call based on the ID's value. The problem still remains though, calling AddCustomer or EditCustomer on the first element makes all the other elements of the list vanish into thin air.

Comment: There doesn't appear to be anything here that would remove the rows from the DataGridView, could you please post the entire code behind? As an aside, have you considered using a datasource for the grid instead and doing the adding and editing of customers on that. This should end up being a bit tidier and you may even be able to push all the validation down into the layer where you finally persist the list within the customer manager class.

Comment: @DavidHall: Thanks for your suggestion, I'll head that way, but the problem still remains; when adding or editing a customer the customerBindingSource.List gets cleared except the first element